# How to query with nested distinct records in Laravel/Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following table structure:

```
Products
========
  id  | name 
------|-------
  1   | A
  2   | B

Stocks
========
  id  | product_id | color_id | size | qty
------|------------|----------|----- |-----
  1   | 1          | 1        | S    | 37
  2   | 1          | 1        | XL   | 89
  3   | 1          | 2        | S    | 6
  4   | 1          | 2        | L    | 8

Colors
========
  id  | name  |  hex
------|-------|-------
  1   | Red   | #ff0000
  2   | Green | #00ff00
```

What I want is to get the list of products with each of its available colors and sizes, so:

```
Product {
  id:               string
  name:             string
  available_sizes:  string[]
  available_colors: Color[]
}
```

I looked up the Laravel documentation and figured that I need to use `hasManyThrough` (probably) to make a relation between `Product <==> Color`. But since my `colors` table doesn't have a `stock_id`, I am not understanding how can I connect them.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

here you will use models
ProductModel

```
public function stocks()
{
return $this->belongsto(StockModel::class,'product_id');
}
StockModel
public function colors()
{
return $this->hasmany(ColorModel::class,'color_id');
}
```

Controller

```
$product=Product::with('stocks.colors')->find($id);
dd($product);
```

and check if the data are available.

or according to the documentation hasmanythrough
ProductModel:

```
public function colors(){
return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Stock::class,
            Color::class,
            'product_id', // Foreign key on the product table...
            'color_id', // Foreign key on the colors table...
            'id', // Local key on the products table...
            'id' // Local key on colors table...
        );
}
```

Controller:

```
$product=Product::with('colors')->find($id);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) works in a scenario that a product has many stocks and a stock has many colors. This is not the case.

You can simply [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship and present the data the way you want, using [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction) and [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#higher-order-messages):

```php
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::with('stocks.color')->get();

    return ProductResource::collection($products);
}

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'available_sizes' => $this->stocks->map->size->unique()->toArray(),
            'available_colors' => $this->stocks
                ->map->color
                ->map->name
                ->unique()
                ->toArray()
        ]
    }
}
```